# Can I submit multiple, separate apps for review?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I can't seem to find an answer to this question. I keeping finding answers to submit multiple builds to the same app, but I can't find answers to multiple, simultaneous app reviews.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: I once read that there were limitations to how many apps you can have under review, but now I can't find documentation that says there is or isn't any limit of that sort. I am referring to submitting new apps to the store as opposed to submitting updates for review

Comment: There are companies with dozens if not hundreds of apps in their accounts. If there's a limit it's probably based more on getting a lot of apps rejected in quick succession. I doubt you'd hit it in any reasonable level of operation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have several different apps submitted for review at the same time.  You can only have a single build per app in review at a time though.

Comment: Is that written somewhere officially?